# Model state returns right away .Net Core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-5.0

I have a custom validation attribute

```
public class IsUsernameAcceptableAttr:ValidationAttribute
{
    
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object username, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var _username = username.ToString();
        if (_username.Length<4)
            return new ValidationResult("Username must be at least 4 characters.");
       
        return ValidationResult.Success;

    }
}
```

in my DTO class I have

```
 public class UserAccountInformationDTO
    {
        [IsUsernameAcceptableAttr]
        public string Username { get; set; }


    }
```

In action method I got

```
public IActionResult UpdateAccountInformationstring(UserAccountInformationDTO accountInfo)
    {
        var ms = ModelState.IsValid;
        return Ok();
        
    }
```

The issue is when model state hits an error it send a response back in `errors` as JSON response. I never get to do anything in the controller or alter the response to a format that i want. What else can i do?

Comment: Is the controller marked with `[ApiController]`? That includes logic to do model validation before the action runs.

Comment: @juunas it is. Model validation runs before action executes but if it gets hit with an error it automatically returns a response of 400 with the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the source of the parameters

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#binding-source-parameter-inference

**Update:**

Add the following codes to your startup ConfigureServices:

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(apiBehaviorOptions => {
    apiBehaviorOptions.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
});
```

Comment: didnt make a difference. still sends a response back right away

Comment: 400 bad request

Comment: OK, as @juunas commented, the [ApiController] attribute makes model validation errors automatically trigger an HTTP 400 response. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#automatic-http-400-responses

Comment: You can add this line in the startup.cs `services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(apiBehaviorOptions => {
        apiBehaviorOptions.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
    });`